# Prefetch alternative vs Filter directly in template

Tags: django, prefetch

I am displaying data with following for loops in my template

```
 {% for soproduct in list_soproduct %}
        {% for bomversion in soproduct.product.material.default_active_bomversions %}
            {% for bom in bomversion.bom_set.all %}
                 {% for production_order in bom.production_order_set.all %}
                  {% endfor %}
             {% endfor %}
         {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Data is coming from following models

```
class SOproduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    so = models.ForeignKey(SO, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=3, default = 0)



class Product(models.Model):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    GTIN = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class BOMVersion(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    material =  models.ForeignKey(Material)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_default = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class BOMVersion_default_active_Manager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(BOMVersion_default_active, self).get_queryset().filter(is_default=True,is_active=True)

class BOMVersionQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(is_active=True)

    def default(self):
        return self.filter(is_default=True)


class BOM(models.Model): 
    bomversion =  models.ForeignKey(BOMVersion)
    material =  models.ForeignKey(Material)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(default =0 ,max_digits=19, decimal_places=3)

class Production_order(models.Model):
    BOM = models.ForeignKey(BOM, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    soproduct = models.ForeignKey(SOproduct, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    quantity_order = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=3)
```

In view I use following prefetch object

```
soproduct = SOproduct.objects.select_related('product__material').prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'product__material__bomversion_set',
        queryset=BOMVersion.objects.default().active(),
        to_attr='default_active_bomversions'
    )
)
```

My problem is that in deepest for loop

> for production_order in bom.production_order_set.all

I want to filter by soproduct so i was wondering how can I modify existing prefetch to accommodate this requirement and if it is possible? Or my only option is to filter directly in the template>

(I dont really understand the Prefetch and what I have tried is not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I'm not sure if this is going to work, but give it a try:

```
soproduct = SOproduct.objects.select_related('product__material').prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'product__material__bomversion_set',
        queryset=BOMVersion.objects.default().active().prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('bom_set', queryset=BOM.objects.all().prefetch_related('production_order_set'))
        ),
        to_attr='default_active_bomversions'
    )
)
```

And then in the template, you do a simple if-check.

```
{% for soproduct in list_soproduct %}
    {% for bomversion in soproduct.product.material.default_active_bomversions %}
        {% for bom in bomversion.bom_set.all %}
             {% for production_order in bom.production_order_set.all %}
                {% if production_order.soproduct == soproduct %}
                    do my staff
                {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Basically what `prefetch_related` do is to fetch related data not via `SQL JOINs` *(this is what `select_related` do)*, but by doing separate query and then merging the results in python. I think the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) do a pretty good job explaining this.

And by using a custom `Prefetch` object we can do two things

1) Alter the default `queryset` which django will use doing `prefetch_related` **(usefull to filter results even more)** and

2) Change the attribute into which django will store the prefetched data (by defaults its into the `myobject.related_set.all()` this is useful when we do additional filtering which changes the contex of the results and `related_set.all()` won't be appropriate or will be a misleading).

Comment: Thank you @Todor , I already implemented this filtering in my template with if condition . But was not able to figure it out how to add this condition into prefetch_related . Do you believe it is not possible to do it in prefetch_related in my situation? Do you think it will affect performance if I do it this way in template instead of prefetch_related?

Comment: The main idea of `prefetch_related` is to do less queries, e.g. in your example the page should load with about 4 queries (only for this part), while if you do it without it will depends on the objects in every relation (this will means, a lot). The code in the template should work in both cases (with and without `prefetch_related`), because all prefetch_related do is to cache for you queries like `bomversion.bom_set.all`, the big deal is that when you use prefetch_related you make less queries. Install some app like `django-debug-toolbar` and check how many queries you have on that page.